# Generators of Special Linear Group of Order n over Integers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am trying to find the generators for the special linear group over the integers with order n. In two dimensions, [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Generators_of_Special_Linear_Group_of_Order_2_over_Integers) solves it elegantly with only two elements. But the proof here seems pretty ad-hoc, and it's not clear to me how it can be generalized to n-dimensional space. Any thoughts on what the generators may look like in n-dimension will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ can be generated by elementary matrices and since reduction $\bmod m$ takes a quotient of this so can any quotient.

Comment: (Strictly speaking we need to know that reduction $\bmod m$ is surjective which is not quite trivial.)

Comment: See [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/181366/34894) from math overflow.